# Unable to compare two values in an array for javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to see if I can get my function to determine the "odd man out" in the array living within the function. Specifically, after I take a string, convert it into numbers and push it into an array -- I want it to be able to loop through the output array and return the index of which number is "the odd man out" (i.e. "2 2 2 2 4 6 8 1" should return index 7 as it is the only odd number). However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to return the index, when the function faces both situations that I listed below in the code.

```
function notSame(numbers){
  var notString = parseInt(numbers.replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10),
  sNumber = notString.toString(),
  output =[];

console.log(sNumber);

for(var i = 0; i < sNumber.length; i+=1) {
    output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));    

}

for(var num1 = 0; num1 < output.length; num1++) {
    for(var num2 = 1; num2 < output.length; num2++) {
    if(output[num1] % output[num2] === 1) {  
        return num1;
        }
    }
  }
}

notSame("2 2 2 2 4 6 8 1"); /// Situation 1: should output index 7 as it is the only odd number
notSame("5 7 9 2 1" ); ///Situation 2: should output index 4 as it is the only even number
```

Comment: notSame("5 7 9 2 1" ); should return 3

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your integers in the `output` array,

```
 // test the first three array members
  var test = Math.abs(output[0])%2 + Math.abs(output[1])%2 + Math.abs(output[2])%2;
 // if the sum of the mods of the first three integers in the 
 // array is more than 1, the array is mostly odd numbers, hence 
 // the odd one out will be even, else it will be odd
  var outlierIsOdd = test >= 2 ? false : true;
 // find the odd one out and return it's index
  return output.indexOf(output.filter(function(e){
    return (Math.abs(e)%2 === +outlierIsOdd);
  })[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to break down the problem into smaller units.

```
// return an array from a string
function toArray(str) { return str.split(' '); }

// return the element if it's even
function even(el) { return el % 2 === 0; }

// return the index of either true/false
function getIndex(arr, flag) { return arr.indexOf(flag); }

// count how many instances of true are in the array
function count(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el;
  }).length;
}

function check(str) {

  // return an array of true/false values
  var evens = toArray(str).map(even);

  // if there is more than 1 true value in `evens`
  // return the index of false from the array
  // otherwise return the index of the only true element
  return count(evens) > 1 ? getIndex(evens, false) : getIndex(evens, true);
}

check('2 2 2 2 4 6 8 1'); // 7
check('5 7 9 2 1'); // 3
check('2 5 2 6 6'); // 1
check('7 7 7 9 1 3 8 1 5') // 6
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/60s1nanf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function notSame(string) {
  var even = [];
  var odd = [];
  string.split(" ").forEach(function(e, i) {
    string.split(" ")[i] % 2 ? odd.push(i) : even.push(i);
  })
  even > odd ? document.write(even) : document.write(odd);
}

notSame("2 2 2 2 4 6 8 1");
```

Fill up 2 arrays with index: 
one for odds and one for evens and compare the length.